# Is it possible to use PhoneGap with iOS applications that require background execution?

Tags: cordova

Is it possible (and if so convenient) to use PhoneGap for iOS applications that require a background mode (voip, location, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, since PhoneGap is nothing special, just a glorified UIWebView. However, GUI won't execute/update in the background. Also, the "convenience" depends on what you are trying to accomplish with your application. If you need VoIP, geoloation or features like that, you have to take advantage of backgrounding. However, you **will** still need to implement those services yourself (as far as I know, PhoneGap doesn't support them natively).

Answer (score 1):

+1, for writing an app that uses background features, you will need to write it natively, you can still use phonegap for the UI and for functionalities used when app is in foreground, from what I have learned, using a combination of native and html 5 wrappers can be very productive, e.g. in one of my apps, I used iphone native code to setup and receive push notifications, and the UI and some of the functionalties were done through phonegap(which resulted in quick development and easy modification of UI).